# Rails how to access child model attributes in where

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have two models:

Campaign and Qualification. Campaign `has_one :qualification` and Qualification `belongs_to :campaign`.

Let's say that Qualification has a `male_gender` boolean attribute, what's the most effective way to find all campaigns that have a qualification with `male_gender` == `true`

One way would be to loop through qualification with `male_gender` indexed. Create an array of campaign_ids, and then get campaigns with those ids, but this seems not very effective.

Ideally I'd like to do something like `Campaign.where("qualification.male_gender: true")`

Is that possible? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly can do this. Using a join you can reference the other table in your where query:

```
Campaign.joins(:qualification).where(qualifications: {male_gender: true})
```

---

*Rich Peck edit*

You could also put this into a [scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope):

```
#app/models/campaign.rb
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :male_gender, -> { joins(:qualification).where(qualifications: {male_gender: true}) }
end
```

... which would allow you to call `@campaigns = Campaign.male_gender`

Comment: Genius! Thanks much!

Comment: Rich - would that be more efficient? Or just for ease of coding?

Comment: Functionally they're identical. However using a scope would allow you to easily use the query in lots of places without duplicating the code everywhere. Same as with any other query really. Anything you're doing in lots of places for the same data request is a good candidate for moving to a scope.